# ValidationMessage for custom property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to make a homepage with asp.net identity. I really want my users to have a custom displayname instead of using thier email as "Welcome, foo@bar.com".

I need help with validating the displayname showing a message in html that name already exist but I have no idea how I should make it.

So far my code works, if your chosen display doesn't exist you will get it, but if it doesn't it will return to the same page, which is intended. But there is no message telling you the displayname already exist, I just have a validator for [Length(14)].

Tell me how should I proceed to tell my users that the display is already taken.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
        }

        DAL.ProjectStrawberryEntities ctx = new DAL.ProjectStrawberryEntities();

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
        Match match = regex.Match(model.DisplayName);

        bool displayNameExist = ctx.AspNetUsers.Any(a => a.Displayname == match.Value);

        if (ModelState.IsValid && !displayNameExist)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, DisplayName = model.DisplayName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

---

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DisplayName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DisplayName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DisplayName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use [ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError%28System.String,System.String%29) to add an error for a property. An instance of this class that will be used by your view, is [ModelState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.modelstate(v=vs.118).aspx) property of your controller.

For example, in your action method, you can write

```
ModelState.AddModelError("DisplayName", "DisplayName already exists.");
```

then return current view instead of redirection.

```
return View();
```

So the code may be like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && !displayNameExist)
{   
     //Save 
     //return RedirectToAction(your action)
     //return Redirect(your redirect url)
}
else
{
     ModelState.AddModelError("DisplayName", "DisplayName already exists.");
     //If you need add something to ViewBag you can do it here
     return View();
}
```

Comment: That worked excellent, this was a really neat way to add custom errors. Thanks a lot!

Comment: JFYI, When you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not compulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) :)